# Show that every element of $G$ can be written as $a^{-1}\Psi(a)$ for some $a \in G$.

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Assume $G$ is a finite group and $\Psi \in \text{Aut(G)}$ such that for every $g \in G:\Psi(g)=g \implies g=e_G$.

Show that every element of $G$ can be written as $a^{-1}\Psi(a)$ for some $a \in G$.

---

I tried to use some basic results, however, these were not helpful, besides I don't know how the condition
$g \in G:\Psi(g)=g \implies g=e_G$ will help us.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional condition is required, as without it the map $\phi: G\rightarrow G$ defined by $g\mapsto\Psi(g)g^{-1}$ is not injective.

We want to prove that the map $\phi: G\rightarrow G$ is surjective. As $G$ is a finite set, this map is surjective if and only if it is injective. We shall prove that the map is injective.

To see that it is injective, suppose $\phi(g)=\phi(h)$, so $\Psi(g)g^{-1}=\Psi(h)h^{-1}$. This rearranges to give $\Psi(h^{-1}g)(h^{-1}g)^{-1}=1$, and so (by the condition) $h^{-1}g=1$, so $h=g$. Hence, the map is injective. It is therefore surjective, by the above, as required.

Comment: No, I am not assuming every element has this form (although the "additional condition" implies that *some non-trivial element* has this form -- can you see why?). The map $g\mapsto \Psi(g)g^{-1}$ is clearly a function from $G$ to $G$, so elements of the image of this map are group elements. So we can do things like rearrange $\Psi(g)g^{-1}=\Psi(h)h^{-1}$ as above, and so on.

Comment: @45465 No, it's not a homomorphism. It's *just* a function.

Comment: Yes, we *want* to show that it is surjective. To do this we prove that the function $G\rightarrow G$ is injective. Surjectivity follows as $G$ is finite.

Comment: Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets, and let $f: A\rightarrow B$ be an injection. As $A$ is an injection $|f(A)|=|A|$, right? Therefore, if $|A|=|B|$ then $f(A)=B$, right? And so we have:  If $A$ and $B$ be finite sets with $|A|=|B|$ and $f: A\rightarrow B$ is an injection, then $f$ is a surjection. This is the same set up as in the answer, as there $G=A=B$ so $|A|=|B|$.

Comment: The sets need to be finite as otherwise we can have an injective, non-surjective map $f:A\rightarrow A$. For example, the map $f:\mathbb{Z\rightarrow Z}$ defined by $n\mapsto 2n$ is injective but not surjective.

Comment: @45465 I've altered the question a bit to make it clearer (whilst also trying to keep it short). Any other suggestions are welcome :-)